# Car ran out of fuel

Tags: project-cars-2

I was playing Project CARS 2, and I ran out of fuel during private testing. All that happened was that my car stopped working.

If this were to happen in real life, the car would be towed back to the garage and refueled.

Is there anything I can do when I run out of fuel in endurance races, apart from quitting or restarting the session?

Answer (score 1):

Watching [this video](https://youtu.be/ZD7jGUqk3cQ?t=3m12s), it appears when you run out of fuel, your car will attempt to restart itself after coming to a stop.  Eventually though, you get taken to the pits, and you get disqualified.  At that point, it looks like you have to end the race.

I'm not sure how the rules in real life races are, but it looks like you don't want to run out of gas in this game, since you essentially forfeit.

Comment: That would be annoying if you were doing a 24hr race and ran out of fuel with 3hr to go while being on the podium.

Comment: @iProgram yup.  I suppose in real life if you ran out of gas during a race, by the time you got towed back to the pits and then refueled, you'd probably be so far behind it wouldn't matter.

Comment: Except for in endurance racing such as Le Mans, it doesn't batter as such because other cars crash out and therefor need a few hours of repairs which would help you to gain time you lost.

Answer (score -1):

Le Mans or Endurance Races does dozens of pitstop to change tires and do refuelling. Unlike Formula One, where pitstop is now just to change the tires, Endurance races requires refuelling and that is something we cannot do even with tuning or changing the fuel mode. Eventually you will run out of fuel if you don't do refuelling in Endurance Races. It can be done by editing your pit strategy. You can do it before the race or midway in the race in the car management panel (YOU NEED TO DEFINE the button to access it). Once the strategy has been defined, just go to the pits before your fuel runs out and the pit crew will do things according to your strategy.

Comment: You're saying that refueling is necessary but cannot be done? That doesn't seem helpful.

Comment: It can be done by editing your pit strategy. You can do it before the race or midway in the race in the car management panel (YOU NEED TO DEFINE the button to access it)

Comment: Once you have defined the strategy, just go to the pit before your fuel runs out in the race. There your crew will do everything according to your strategy